# Retorno Json PHP para Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Seguinte eu tenho uma variável em *cliente.php* que imprime :

```
   [{"CODIGO_CLIENTE":3,"CGC":"78.079.128\/0001-80","RAZAO":"Cliente 2","FANTASIA":"Cliente 2","TELEFONE1":"+99(99)9999-9999"},
    {"CODIGO_CLIENTE":2,"CGC":"14.617.787\/0001-40","RAZAO":"Cliente 1","FANTASIA":"Cliente 1","TELEFONE1":"+99(99)9999-9999"},
    {"CODIGO_CLIENTE":5,"CGC":"54.731.556\/0001-87","RAZAO":"Cliente 3","FANTASIA":"Cliente 3","TELEFONE1":"+99(99)9999-9999"},
    {"CODIGO_CLIENTE":6,"CGC":"55.765.452\/0001-56","RAZAO":"Cliente 4","FANTASIA":"Cliente 4","TELEFONE1":"+99(99)9999-9999"}]
```

E tento pegar o Json via Ajax da seguinte forma:

```
    $('#btn-sinc').click(function() {   
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost/read/cliente.php",
        crossDomain: true,      
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',       
        success : function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            for(var i=0; i < responseData.length; i++){
                var html = "";
                    html += '<tr>'; 
                    html += '<td data-label="Cnpj">'+responseData[i].CGC+'</td>';
                    html += '<td data-label="Razão">'+responseData[i].RAZAO+'</td>';                    
                    html += '<td data-label="Fantasia">'+responseData[i].FANTASIA+'</td>';                  
                    html += '<td data-label="Telefone">'+responseData[i].TELEFONE1+'</td>';                          
                    html += '</tr>';                   
            }

            $('.table').html(html);         
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.warn(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('Falha');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Ele só está imprimindo a ultima informação do *cliente.php*:

```
{"CODIGO_CLIENTE":6,"CGC":"55.765.452\/0001-56","RAZAO":"Cliente 4","FANTASIA":"Cliente 4","TELEFONE1":"+99(99)9999-9999"}
```

Imagino pelo fato de ser um Json, ele só irá pegar a ultima informação, mas existe alguma maneira de eu conseguir pegar todas no formato Json?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema não tem a ver com AJAX nem JSON, é erro na lógica usada. Seu código está zerando a variável `html` dentro do loop todas as vezes.

Passe o `html = ""` para fora do loop, assim:

```
var html = "";
for(var i=0; i < responseData.length; i++){
    html += '<tr>'; 
    html += '<td data-label="Cnpj">'+responseData[i].CGC+'</td>';
    html += '<td data-label="Razão">'+responseData[i].RAZAO+'</td>';                    
    html += '<td data-label="Fantasia">'+responseData[i].FANTASIA+'</td>';                  
    html += '<td data-label="Telefone">'+responseData[i].TELEFONE1+'</td>';                           html += '</tr>';                   
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo obrigado!